# how to extract only time from datetime

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I'm working with datasets comprising two strings columns. Date and time such as :

```
Date                      Time                       Expiry
'2018-01-29 00:00:00'     '1900-01-01 12:40:59'       '2018-02-22 15:30:00'
```

What I want to do is extract the time from the 'Time' column and replace '00:00:00' in the 'Date' column so I would obtain Date + Time, like so :

```
Output : 2018-01-29 12:40:59
```

I've tried converting the Time string using timedelta():

```
temp['Time1']=pd.to_timedelta(temp['Time'])
```

But the output isn't quite what i want:

```
-25567 days +12:40:59
```

After this, I would then like to subtract the result from the column 'Expiry', to get an output of time remaining :

```
Expiry - Date + Time
2018-02-22 15:30:00 - 2018-01-29 12:40:59

Expected output: 24.11 days
```

I'm very new to python, so pardon the slightly amateurish description and formatting. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2018-01-29 00:00:00'],
                   'time': ['1900-01-01 12:40:59']})

df['datetime'] = df.date.str.split().str[0] + ' ' + df.time.str.split().str[1]
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

print(df)
```

```
                  date                 time            datetime
0  2018-01-29 00:00:00  1900-01-01 12:40:59 2018-01-29 12:40:59
```

Answer (score 0):

you can extract everything from datetime using the following examples:

```
datetime.year
datetime.month
datetime.day
```

You could take a look at the official python documentation:  [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)